# Jquery each <li> apply mouseover background

Tags: jquery, html-lists, mouseover, each, background-color

Can't seem to get this to work:

```
$(function() {
  $("#side").$("li").each(function() {
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
      $(this).backgroundColor = "#c0c0c0";
    });
  });
});
```

The HTML snippet to iterate over:

```
<div id='side'>
   <ul>
      <li>A</li>
      <li>B</li>
      <li>C</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the error? Can you please post the HTML code as well?

Comment: A jQuery object does neither have a `$` nor a `backgroundColor` property. *Why do you think it has?* I suggest to read one of the [jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) and have a look at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/). It seems you have to learn the basics first.

Comment: You're right. I'm used to plain Javascript so I try to learn a bit of jQuery then start hacking. I should spend more time reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(function() {
    $("#side").children("li").each(function() {
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css ("background-Color", "#c0c0c0");
        });
        $(this).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).css("background-Color", "#FFF"); 
        });
    });
});​
```

The issues I saw were:

1. The selector you were using for your ul/li was incorrect.  You need to use the children method.
2. Changing the css is different in jquery then javascript.  Use the css method instead.
3. Make sure to change the color back to default (in this case white) when the mouse leaves.  Otherwise it will always be that grey (even when the mouse leaves).

The JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8hsz/
Hope that helps.

EDIT: If you're worried about the background color, you can do something similar to:

```
$(function() {
    $("#side").children("li").each(function() {
        $(this).data("DefaultBGColor", $(this).css("background-color"));
        $(this).mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css ("background-Color", "#c0c0c0");
        });
        $(this).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).css("background-Color", $(this).data("DefaultBGColor")); 
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: Marvelous! PS: I had to make one alteration:
`$("#side > ul").children("li").each` to get it to work for me ^^

Comment: ah, with my code the ul had the id of side, so yours I'm guessing you encased the ul with a div with the id of side?

Comment: Correct! :) Look up! ;) But you're a genius, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the hover event as well:

```
$(function() {
    $("#side").children("li").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css ("background-Color", "#c0c0c0");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css("background-Color", "#FFF"); 
        }
   );
});​
```

Comment: What is the second part for with setting to white? Is there a way for it to be a temporary change? This seems like it is going to forget the previous background-Color setting? 

I want to maintain the hard-coded background-Color which may be different among each list item, anyway will try this!

Comment: @eyafed: Then you have to store the original color first, before you assign a new one. E.g. using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: You could use $(this).removeAttr('style'); instead of setting it back to #fff

Comment: I'm testing and I really can't get the example above to work.
With my HTML snippet in the question, are you certain that this works?  Does the children of $('#side') only pick up <ul>?

Comment: I changed it $("#side > ul").children("li").each and it worked. Thanks  though!

Answer (score 1):

Just an fyi - for li block hover effects, you do not need javascript or Jquery, this can be done 100% in CSS.  The only exclusion is if you need to work with IE6.

I forked Ben's comment above:

http://jsfiddle.net/stevembrennan/tLZNL/

**Markup from Original Example**

1

2

3

**CSS to add**

```
ul {float:left; left:0; position:absolute; right:auto;  width:auto;}
li {clear:left; float: left; left:auto; margin:0px; width:100%; text-align:left;      display:block; background-color:#00a0e1;}
li a {display:block; padding:4px 10px;}
li a:hover {background-color:red;}
```

No JS needed

If you need help on how to do this in IE6, let me know.  There is a trick in which you can add a block element around the entire thing and it will trick the hover into kicking in.  Apologies for such a late reply.